# When I do a put axios returns ERR_NETWORK

Tags: javascript, axios, cors, vuejs3

When I wanna send the object to Route, axios returns me ERR_NETWORK. I don't know if CORS is envolved.

[Here I show you the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCwR0.png)

My services.js:

```
import axios from "axios";

export const apiClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://laboratorio3-f36a.restdb.io/rest',
    headers: {'x-apikey': '60eb09146661365596af552f',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:8080',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': '*',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    },
    
    
});
export default{
    

    transaction(purchaseData){
        return apiClient.post(`/transaction/`, purchaseData)
    },
    getHistorial(id){
        return apiClient.get(`/transactions/${id}`)
    },
    delete(id){
        return apiClient.delete(`/transactions/${id}`)
    },
    edit(id){
        return apiClient.put(`/transactions/${id}`)
    }

}
```

Here I send Object:

```
   const Purchase = async () => {          
                console.log('Los datos son: ',purchaseData)
                
                try {
                    console.log('Enviando....')
                    await lab3api.transaction(purchaseData);
                    console.log('Enviaooouu')
                } catch(e) {
                    console.log("Error en la compra", e)
                }
        }
```

I've tried installing cors libraries. I added the headers Acces-Control-Allow-Methods but that doesn't work either. I've installed an extension that supposedly allows CORS, etc, etc, etc

Comment: The details of Network errors are not exposed to JS. You need to look at any error messages reported directly to the console. You should also look at the network tab to see what sort of response you are actually getting to your request.

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about providing error messages as text and not as pictures of text.

Comment: ```'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' : '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : 'http://localhost:8080',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': '*',``` is a load of nonsense. Permission for your JS to read the data from the server has to be given by the server. Your code can't give itself permission to read the data.